# Problems with this code (Sorry I can't be specific)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, char

trying to write a program which assigns a char array (ch) values from 65 to 90.I'm then trying to print this like so:

```
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z
```

I'm trying to do this with two loops, having A LOT of trouble. This is what i have so far:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Lab10a {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            char ch[] =new char[26];
            for (int x = 0; x < ch.length; x++){
                ch[x] = (char)(x + 65);
                for(int i = 0, i < ch.length; i++)[


                }
            }
     //It doesn't need to be converted to a string here, this is just a method i tried.
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ch) + ", ");
        }
    }
```

This is the printout im getting currently:

```
    [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z],
```

Sorry that my coding is so unclear, really not too sure how to go about this. Suggestions?

Comment: The title of the Question is not useful at all (zero googlability). I'm not versed in Java but what about `"Assigning char array values within two loops"`?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
        for (int x = 0; x < ch.length; x++){
            ch[x] = (char)(x + 65);                
        }

        for(int i = 0, i < ch.length; i++){
             if((ch.length-1)==i){
                  System.out.print(ch[i]);
             }else{
                  System.out.print(ch[i] + ", ");
             } 
        }
```

Comment: You still get one extra `", "` at the end of the line this way.

Comment: Thanks, But how do i get rid of the ", " that prints after the Z?

Answer (score 0):

```
String out = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
     out += ", " + ch[i];
System.out.println(out.subString(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  char ch[] =new char[26];
  for (int x = 0; x < ch.length; x++){
      ch[x] = (char)(x + 'A');
  }
  // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ch));
  boolean first = true;
  for (char c : ch) {
    if (! first) {
      System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.print(c);
    first = false;
  }
  System.out.println();
  System.out.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and works**:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab10a {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      char ch[] =new char[26];
      for (int x = 0; x < ch.length; x++){
          ch[x] = (char)(x + 65);
      }

      // for every char in the char array (except the last one), 
      // print it with a comma 
      for (int i = 0; i < ch.length - 1; i++) 
          System.out.print(ch[i] + ", ");

      System.out.print(ch[ch.length - 1]); // print the last one without a comma
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do, what you did but also use str = str.replace().

For example:

```
String str = Arrays.toString(ch);
str = str.replace(",", "");
str = str.replace("[", "");
str = str.replace("]", "");
```

then simply print the string.

haven't tested this but should work.